# django как сделать ссылку на прямое скачивания файла?

Tags: python, django, html5

Развернул сервер на apache(xampp) + django + mod_wsgi

Как можно сделать прямое скачивание файлов с данного сервера по его адресу/ссылке
например так: **80.85.210.62/file.json/mp3/pdf**

Как лучще сделать так ? разместить ссылку на html странице или иной способ

Comment: в settings.py создайте настройку с адресом папки для раздачи, через os.path, os.dir, os.isfile и тп отдаете ссылки, а файл отдаете через https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects или средствами апача / nginx. Во втором случае нужно просто сформировать  url

Comment: спасибо за ссылку направление куда смотреть:)

Comment: @ZaArs сервить через python код само содержимое файла - очень плохое решение.  Максимум чего бы я порекомендовал в случае необходимости контроля доступа например - использовать что то типа X-Accel-Redirect от nginx

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич знаю, поэтому указал, как второй вариант  раздачу через nginx/apache